# Возможно ли задать свои варианты для времени в виджете SplitDateTimeWidget?

Tags: django

В Django для задания DateTimeField используется TextInput с виджетом SplitDateTimeWidget. Возможно ли, и, если да, то как для этого виджета задать свое перечисление вариантов для времени?

Comment: Вопрос не про задание формата, а про задание значений - вариантов для выбора

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно:
DateTimeField принимает один необязательный аргумент:

input_formats
Список форматов, используемых при попытках сконвертировать строку в объект datetime.datetime.

Если аргумент input_formats не предоставлен, то используются следующие форматы:

```
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',    # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
'%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
'%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
'%m/%d/%y']              # '10/25/06'
```